# HNGARCHFIT in R (No standard deviations or P values printed)

Tags: option-pricing, programming, garch, european-options

When I estimate an HN-GARCH model using the hngarchfit() from the fOptions package in R, only the coefficient estimates are printed. There are no standard deviations or P-values printed. Does anyone know how to obtain these values?

Best regards

August

Comment: Is this of any help? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fOptions/versions/3042.86/topics/HestonNandiGarchFit

Comment: Sadly not, Kermittfrog. The link does not provide any solution to the printing of standard deviations, t-values or P-values.